# Add a value to a name in a member of an object

Tags: powershell-3.0

I have looked all over and can't seem to find the answer. I'll try to break this down as simple as possible.

I have an array...

```
$arr = @("abc", "dfg", "jkl")
```

Now I want to create an object (which will eventually be exported to a csv file). With the object, I want the name to be 'ListOfStrings' and the values to be plugged in from the array.

so something like this...

```
$objListOfStrings = New-Object PSObject

$objListOfStrings | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "ListOfStrings" -value "$arr[0]"
$objListOfStrings | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "ListOfStrings" -value "$arr[1]"
$objListOfStrings | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "ListOfStrings" -value "$arr[2]"
$objListOfStrings | Format-Table
```

The output looks like this...

```
ListOfStrings
-------------
abc dfg jkl
```

Instead, I'm trying to get the output to look like this...

```
ListOfStrings
-------------
abc
dfg
jkl
```

Anyone who can help me with this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each line in the list of your desired output is a separate object. Instead of adding properties to one object, create an object per array element using the `ListOfStrings` property:

```
$arr = "abc", "dfg", "jkl"

$objListOfStrings  = $arr | % {
   [PSCustomObject] @{
      ListOfStrings = $_
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it to work after 8 hours of trying different things. This looks similar to what I tried last night. I'll give this a shot too when I get back into work. The syntax though makes my eyes want to bleed. Oh well, guess I have a lot to learn about powershell. I've been stuck in java and python for too long... Thanks again for your help, if it works I'll check you as the answer.